# How to find a free VPC CIDR block with Ansible?

Tags: python, yaml, ansible, cidr, vpc

I've got an existing set of VPC's in AWS, each with their own CIDR blocks:

vpc1: 20.0.0.0/16
vpc2: 20.10.0.0/16

Now, I'm trying to write a playbook, which pulls in the existing list of VPC's and then finds an available CIDR (e.g. in the above example, the next available one would be 20.20.0.0/16, though I'm not too concerned about keeping it sequential).

I know that doing this works with two lists:

```
- name: Loop over all possible CIDRs
    debug: msg="Found a free CIDR {{ item }}"
    with_items: all_potential_cidrs
    when: "\"{{ item }}\" not in {{ currently_used_cidrs }}"
```

However, the way I'm getting the list of existing CIDRs is:

```
- name: Get list of VPCs and their CIDR blocks
  command: aws ec2 describe-vpcs --output json
  register: cli_output

- name: Register variables
  set_fact:
  current_vpcs: "{{ cli_output.stdout | from_json }}"
```

The command gives the following data back (in JSON format):

```
{
    "Vpcs": [
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-4aad0c23",
            "InstanceTenancy": "default",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "vpc1",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "State": "available",
            "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-ff6b238f",
            "CidrBlock": "20.0.0.0/16",
            "IsDefault": false
        },
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-d4101abc",
            "InstanceTenancy": "default",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "vpc2",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "State": "available",
            "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-eaaab38c",
            "CidrBlock": "20.10.0.0/16",
            "IsDefault": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Which allows getting all CIDR blocks as follows:

```
- name: Print filtered VPCs and their subnets
  debug: msg="VPC ID {{ item.VpcId }}, VPC CIDR block {{ item.CidrBlock }}"
  with_items: current_vpcs.Vpcs
```

However, as "CidrBlock" is a property of a list item, I'm unable to use it in the "when" statement, which requires a List:

```
when: "{{ item }}" not in {{ list_of_cidrs }}"
```

How can I take the "CidrBlock" property of each of the "Vpcs" items and turn it into it's own list, in order to pass it to the "when: ... not in ..." statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the list of VPC `item`s into a list of just the CIDR blocks using [Jinja's map filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map).

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish what this playbook, but here's an example that allows you to convert the list of "Vpcs" items into a list of strings that are the `CidrBlock` of each vpc item.

You can see it working in:

```
- name: Print just the CIDRS
  debug: msg='{{ current_vpcs.Vpcs|map(attribute="CidrBlock")|list }}'
```

Assuming you have `current_vpcs` set, the line above outputs

```
TASK: [Print just the CIDRS] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "[u'20.0.0.0/16', u'20.10.0.0/16']"
 }
```

---

Full working example:

```
---
- name: ok
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    all_available_cidrs:
      - "20.0.0.0/16"
      - "20.10.0.0/16"
      - "20.20.0.0/16"

  tasks:

    - name: Get list of VPCs and their CIDR blocks
      command: aws ec2 describe-vpcs --output json
      register: cli_output

    - name: Register variables
      set_fact:
        current_vpcs: "{{ cli_output.stdout | from_json }}"

    - name: Print VPCs and their subnets
      debug: msg="VPC ID {{ item.VpcId }}, VPC CIDR block {{ item.CidrBlock }}"
      with_items: current_vpcs.Vpcs

    - name: extract list_of_cidrs into fact
      set_fact: 
        list_of_cidrs: '{{ current_vpcs.Vpcs|map(attribute="CidrBlock")|list|to_json }}'

    - name: Print just the CIDRS
      debug: var=list_of_cidrs

    - name: Print available unused cidrs
      debug: msg="available unused VPC CIDR block {{ item }}"
      with_items: all_available_cidrs
      when: '"{{ item }}" not in {{ list_of_cidrs }}'
```

The line that turns `current_vpcs.Vpcs` into the list `["20.0.0.0/16", "20.10.0.0/16"]` is:

```
set_fact: 
  list_of_cidrs: '{{ current_vpcs.Vpcs|map(attribute="CidrBlock")|list|to_json }}'
```

---

**Note**: it is necessary to use `|list|to_json` to get Jinja to template the `in` statement properly. `map` returns a generator whose representation can't be used as the argument of a Jinja `in` statement. There may be a cleaner way to do this, but using `|list|to_json` is the solution people found in [This ticket](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/issues/288)

---

**Edit**: add variable `all_available_cidrs` to make the full example closer match the original question

Comment: That is brilliant! I had no idea about Jinja's "map" or "list" filters. Thank you so much for this, have been racking my brain to find a way to do this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

In `ansible [core 2.14.1]` the solution from dex didn't work for me. I always got this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'CidrBlock'.
```

This is how I solved it (vpc-id is random/not mine, replace with yours):

```
---
### this file is for testing/development purposes
- name: Testing Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Getting info of vpc subnets
      amazon.aws.ec2_vpc_subnet_info:
        filters:
          vpc-id: vpc-1c21424f3a1964893
      register: sn

    - name: Registering used cidr blocks variable
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        cidr_used: []

    - name: Add list of used cidr blocks to cidr_used
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        cidr_used: "{{ cidr_used + [item.cidr_block] }}"
      with_items: "{{ sn.subnets }}"

    - name: Checking avaible cidr blocks
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        cidr_selection: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ cidr_available | reverse }}"
      when: item not in cidr_used

    - name: Output cidr_used
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ cidr_selection }}"

  vars:
    cidr_available:
    - 10.0.1.0/28
    - 10.0.1.48/28
    - 10.0.1.64/28
    - 10.0.1.80/28
    - 10.0.1.96/28
    - 10.0.1.112/28
    - 10.0.1.128/28
    - 10.0.1.144/28
    - 10.0.1.160/28
    - 10.0.1.176/28
    - 10.0.1.192/28
    - 10.0.1.208/28
    - 10.0.1.224/28
```

...where `cidr_selection` will become the first unused cidr block. I had to use the `reverse` function, otherwise the last cidr block in my list would've been assigned first.

Also, I chose to not use the `ansible.builtin.command` collection to simplify it just a little bit more.